# Caption or title: which should I use?

Tags: publications, writing

I have a figure in my paper. If there is much to say about the figure, I will have a brief title and a descriptive caption for it.

What about the figure about which I have not much too say? Do I replicate what I have written in the title in the caption?

Since caption is also used for reference, it must exist. Can I then remove the figure title and use the caption only?

Answer (score 4):

What is your paper for? I think figures (for example in journal articles or thesis) usuaully have a caption below them, in addition to their number:

> **Figure 1.**  Cumulative food intake in rats during intragastric treatment

But typically there is no "title", unless you have a "list of figures" somewhere in the beginning of the document: then it is ok to use the same phrase as caption and title, because they are not written at the same place.

Comment: +1 for *typically there is no "title"*. Indeed so. Seems that everything in caption is a convention and also space-saving!

Comment: I've seen titles used in figures. Often it's a bad habit inherited by those who generate their graphs in Matlab, save the raw image and then insert it in a document as an image. Since Matlab has a `title("something")` command, some people think it is good to use it in their plots before exporting them as pictures. Or, more often, they use the same code to draw the graph onscreen and to generate the image.

Answer (score 2):

My preferred format is

No title in the figure

in the caption
small title. very extended caption describing the figure and a small summary of the results addressed by the figure